# Using LCD 400x240 with HDMI- LVDS Adapter

Tags: hdmi, lcd, lvds

I'd like to get RPi working with my display on the car. The display's specs are here:

https://file.io/w86H2M

Internally it is 6-bit parallel LCD --> 18-bit resolution.

The display housing has connector of LVDS type, it has 8 pins. I checked the pinouts and they are 2 for Red (+ and -), 2 for Green, 2 for Blue and 2 for clock.

There are HDMI to LVDS converters on eBay for sale which I was planning to use.

Timings are here (taken from PDF) :

[image: timings]

My question is will I be able to create proper HDMI timing config for this LCD screen and have the converter display picture through LVDS correctly in 400x240 screen ?

Thanks,
Michael